Why is the Coinbase Data Size limited to 100bytes?
I just read on chapter 12 from Mastering Bitcoin (3rd edition) that the coinbase data size is limited to 100 bytes, why is that?


The 100 byte coinbase limit exists because Satoshi introduced it without giving a justification, and nobody has since gone through the tremendous effort of trying to get the ecosystem to agree to a hardfork to remove it.

There is very small significant data to put there. Why not to limit the size of this field? 100 bytes is more than enough

Yes is more than enough but still not a reason to limit it. If it's enough, then more will not be used but it doesn't need a limitation for this reason.
